# pyserial: set the ring indicator (RI) manually

Tags: python, pyserial

I just want to set the RI Pin on my rs232 to high and low manually. I found a lot of examples to write and read bytes, but I just have to set this one pin. So here is some code copied from examples ...

```
import serial

import serial.tools.list_ports as port_list





ports = list(port_list.comports())


print(ports[0].device)

port = ports[0].device

baudrate = 9600

serialPort = serial.Serial(port=port, baudrate=baudrate,
                            bytesize=8, timeout=1, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
# what I want to do: 
serial.setRI(high)
sleep(5)
serial.setRI(low)
```

Does anybody has an idea what I have to call to set RI?

Comment: Did you check the PySerial documentation? https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#classes - I guess not. Well, search and you'll find it.

Comment: Well, there is only a getter method, but no setter...

Comment: Correct. RI is an input only. Maybe you could repurpose one of the output pins.

Comment: Okay. Bad trap I stepped into....

Comment: Reading the documentation usually helps :-)

Comment: Not if you are seaching something, what does not exist.

Comment: Yes I can understand that might be disappointing, but the upside is now you know how to see what is available, without the risk/delays of asking a question here for every little tidbit of information. Good luck!